# Looking for a book about a boy who had to stay aligned in a particular direction

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a story (probably a novel, but could have been something shorter) about a boy who always had to stay aligned in a particular direction.  He always had to undo turns he made, and then eventually had to start compensating for the earth's rotation, revolution around the sun, and so forth.  This was probably published in the sixties or seventies, but could have been older than that.

Does this sound familiar?

Comment: @MrLister Yes, it does sound like OCD.  It's an SF story that gives what sounds like OCD an actual explanation.

Comment: @Richard Bingo!  That's it!  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Revolving Boy](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872243.The_Revolving_Boy) by Gertrude Friedberg

> Derv had always known that some day he would learn a frightening truth about himself.
>   Now Derv knew the truth - and terror became delight.
>   He was the only human being ever to have been born weightless in free flight.
>   At last Derv felt wholly in tune with the outside influence which had turned and pulled him since birth - the Direction.
>   It was this extraordinary talent that led to Project Ozma

[image]